# stub_status metrics page used in nginx does not show

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I have this .conf file for nginx

> ```
> server {
>     listen 8080;
>
>     server_name _;
>
>     location /status {
>         stub_status;
>     }
> }
> ```

After I used it, I have reloaded NGINX and found out that on my_ip:8080/status there is no page. I checked nginx.conf and it has `include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;` where my .conf is located originally.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The config looks OK.

- What version of nginx you are running? Prior to version 1.7.5 directive `stub_status` required an argument: `stub_status on;`
- Is your nginx built with corresponding module? To be sure, you can run `nginx -V` command and check if there in `--with-http_stub_status_module` in listed config parameters. If not, you need to rebuild nginx with this module enabled.
- Is your .conf really loaded by nginx? Try to dump whole congfiguration with `nginx -T` command and check, if your config is present there.